# pgfplots sort values of input before plotting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot

\pgfplotsset{general plot/.style={
        date coordinates in=x,
        date ZERO=2019-12-31,
        width=37cm,
        height=20cm,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        table/create on use/d/.style={create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{y}}},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[general plot]
        \addplot
        table[x=Date, y=d, col sep=space] {data.csv};
        \addlegendentry{legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With my `data.csv` file looking like this:

```
Date        y
2020-03-20  1
2020-03-19  2
2020-03-18  3
2020-03-17  4
2020-03-16  5
2020-03-15  6
2020-03-14  7
2020-03-13  8
2020-03-12  9
2020-03-11  10
```

I get a curve that goes down (of course since the new column is created on the given table). What I want now, is to sort the values in the table (with the date as key) first and create the new column afterwards.

Anyone out there how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\pgfplotstablesort` macro from the `pgfplotstable` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot

\pgfplotsset{general plot/.style={
        date coordinates in=x,
        date ZERO=2019-12-31,
        width=37cm,
        height=20cm,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        table/create on use/d/.style={create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{y}}},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{data.csv}{\loadedtable}%
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key = Date, sort cmp = date <]{\sortedtable}{\loadedtable}
    \begin{axis}[general plot]
        \addplot
        table[x=Date, y=d, col sep=space] from \sortedtable;
        \addlegendentry{legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there some option to do this without using `\pgfplotstableread`? In the manual it is described that this is only recommended for small inputs. And I don't need to sort completely, a reverse option would be enough

Comment: No more than pgfplots should only be used on small datasets.